# How do I access the Android mobile gallery in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I access the Android mobile gallery in Unity?

Is there any source code available?

How do I pick an image from the gallery in Unity3D?

Comment: If you just want to select an image from the gallery you can use the Native Gallery Assist plugin for Unity -  http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/introducing-native-gallery-assist-ios-android-editor-emulator.403459/

Answer (score 0):

For this, [Image, Video and Contact Picker](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28597) and [App Launcher](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20454) are available on the Unity Asset Store.

If you don't want to download/purchase a plugin, then you will have to write a plugin [yourself](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-gallery-on-unity3d.128668/).